# UI updates with Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having issues finding a way to update the UI AFTER adding to a collection. So in the example below after you click the button and add to the collection an additional input is added to the DOM. All good, but i'd like to find a way to target the new input element and preferably give it focus in addition to CSS. Unfortunately I can't find any info that helps solve this AFTER the DOM's been updated. Any ideas? Thanks

```
<body>
  {{> myTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#each myCollection}}
        <input type="text" value="{{name}}"><br>
    {{/each}}
    <br>
    <button>Click</button><input type="text" value="test" name="testBox">
</template>

test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myTemplate.rendered = function()
    {
        console.log("rendered");
        this.$('input').focus() 
    }
    Template.myTemplate.helpers({
        'myCollection' : function(){
            var testCollection = test.find({});
            console.log("helpers");
            return testCollection;
        }
    });
    Template.myTemplate.events({
        'click button': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var val = $('[name="testBox"]').val();
            console.log("events");
            return test.insert({name: val});
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn what you're adding into a template and call that template's `rendered` to set the needed css or do whatever transforms are needed.

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> myTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="item">
    <input type="text" value="{{name}}"><br>
</template>

<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#each myCollection}}
        {{> item this}}
    {{/each}}
    <br>
    <button>Click</button><input type="text" value="test" name="testBox">
</template>
```

JS:

```
test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
        console.log("rendered");
        this.$('input').focus() 
    });
    Template.myTemplate.helpers({
        'myCollection' : function(){
            var testCollection = test.find({});
            console.log("helpers");
            return testCollection;
        }
    });
    Template.myTemplate.events({
        'click button': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var val = $('[name="testBox"]').val();
            console.log("events");
            test.insert({name: val});
        }
    });
    Template.item.onRendered(function() {
        this.$('input').focus();
    }
}
```

On a side note, you should use `onRendered` instead of `rendered` as the latter has been deprecated for the former.

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense now on how Blaze templating is setup. Each time that template is rendered into the DOM the onRender event is called. Well that's just too simple. 

I'm finding it hard to get my mind around how Meteor can do that work for me. I'm so use to wiring up all that myself. But I must say Meteor is looking better and better all the time. Last week was getting use to having the collection being the one source of truth and again letting it do that part of the job for me. Thanks again Kassym

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside of your myCollection helper function. Use jquery to target the last input in your template and focus it, add css. Meteor's template helpers are reactive computations based on the DOMs usage of their reactive variables, so it will run each time the DOM updates based on your collection.